# Change firefox toolbar color without installing add-on

Tags: firefox

I would like to change the color of the toolbar in Firefox, without installing the "Firefox Color" add-on, nor installing a theme from another developer.

How can I apply my own choice of colour? I have looked at

- command-line arguments when starting firefox
- `prefs.js` customization

but haven't been able to find how. This seems so simple, there must be a way to do so.

I have found a solution with setting a `userChrome.css` but this seems to be using a setting that is turned off by default by firefox, and is legacy, so I am hesitant to use that.

Comment: examine the files in the add-on

Comment: is it open source?

Comment: I do not know ... the files in the add-on may be human readable and may reveal how colors are changed

Comment: `userChrome.css` is the go-to solution for any kind of power user customization of the Firefox UI. See [r/FirefoxCSS](https://www.reddit.com/r/FirefoxCSS/) for examples. I use it constantly. What do you mean by legacy?

Comment: What I mean is that to use userChrome.css, one has to set `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to true in `about:config`. I am not sure if this increases security risks somehow.

Comment: It has nothing to do with security, rather they wanted to reduce the startup cost of checking for a userChrome.css file: https://twitter.com/FirefoxNightly/status/1131287595563065344. There's no need to check for the file if most users don't use it so they put it behind a preference.